# Transaction replication with horizontal filtering

Tags: sql-server, replication

To make a long story short, is it possible to replicate rows of a table in SQL server with horizontal filtering function that being evaluated continuously?

For instance, I need to replicate a table rows to subscriber which are created or updated since last two days or more. I need any rows that are being created in source table but their creation date is older than two days get replicated to subscriber and this get done continuously on any newly created/updated rows. I mean that I don't need to replicate records that are newer than two days.

I have tried transaction replication with filtering function on SQL server 2017, but filtering function just get evaluated on replication creation time and after that, any new rows didn't get propagated to subscriber.

Comment: Have you tried creating an indexed view, and replicating that?

Comment: That sounds a good solution, but I didn't give a try. I will let you know the result after doing this as a test.

Comment: I have used below code for creating indexed view. But it failed with below error message:

CREATE VIEW dbo.I_View
WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[T_Test]
  WHERE [xDate] < DATEADD(MINUTE,-10,GETDATE())
GO
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX I_View_IndexedView
ON dbo.I_View([xID])

Msg 1949, Level 16, State 1, Line 21
Cannot create index on view 'Repl_Test.dbo.I_View'. The function 'getdate' yields nondeterministic results. Use a deterministic system function, or modify the user-defined function to return deterministic results.

Comment: I thinks this is the main problem I have with replication filter also. The [where] clause is exactly what I have used on replication filter and it just evaluated on replication creation time. So it can't determine newly add/updated rows and replicate them after specified period.

Comment: One more question, now that I re-read: are you also saying that you want updates to wait for two days? I.e. I update an existing row (old, already replicated to the subscriber) and that change is only replicated and visible at the subscriber two days later?

Comment: Forget about propagating updates after two days, I don't like complicated situation. my issue is simply to replicate any newly added record just after two days to the subscribers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Add a column to your table: `Alter Table yourTable Add Old_Enough Bit Not Null Default 0`
- Create a job that runs regularly (e.g. hourly) and runs `Update yourTable Set Old_Enough = 1 Where Old_Enough = 0 And DateAdd(Day, 2, yourCreationDateColumn) < GetDate()`
- Create an indexed view that takes `Select ... From yourTable Where Old_Enough = 1`
- Replicate your indexed view